# Rails delegated attribute not in @attributes, read_attribute returns nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model which delegates some methods and attributes to a different model, let's say

```
class ModelOne < ActiveRecord::Base
  # this model has some_property column in database
end
```

and

```
class ModelTwo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :model_one

  delegate :some_property, :to => :model_one
end
```

The problem is that I can access 'some_property' by calling the method but not through read_attribute.

```
> obj1 = ModelTwo.last
> obj1.some_property
=> "some value"
> obj1.read_attribute :some_property
=> nil
> obj1.inspect
=> "#ModelTwo ... , ... , some_property: nil "
```

It is possible to set this attribute:

```
> obj1.some_property = "some value"
> obj1.inspect
=> "#ModelTwo ... , ... , some_property: "some value" "
```

So I can access delegated attribute by calling it but not by read_attribute or through inspect. Is there any chance to get the attribute value by read_attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to override read_attribute method. I am not using read_attribute, but in a similar scenario I had to override the hash method:

```
def [](key)
  value = super
  return value if value
  if super(key+"_id")
    begin
      send(key)
    rescue NoMethodError
    end
  end
end
```

Its not pretty and there are possibly security issues with calling *send(key)* without more accurate validation.

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the implementation of read_attribute:

```
         # File activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb, line 128
          def read_attribute(attr_name)
             self.class.type_cast_attribute(attr_name, @attributes, @attributes_cache)
          end
```

is not based on the attribute accessor (in your case some_property) but is accessing the @attributes instance variable directly, which makes sense because read_attribute is a lower level api that allows you to bypass the accessor. Thus, you can't do what you're trying.

This may not be the answer you're looking for, but what I'd be reconsidering in your design is why you need to access your attribute via read_attribute. If you show us where and how you're using read_attribute, I'll be happy to try and help you farther.